# DotNet.Highcharts Package Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dotnethighcharts

I am following a tutorial [how-to-use-highcharts-js-with-asp-net-mvc-4](https://csharptrenches.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/how-to-use-highcharts-js-with-asp-net-mvc-4/)

and when I build the application I receive the error

The Type or namespace name 'DotNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or and assembly reference?)

I have in my controller

```
using HighChart.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DotNet.Highcharts;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Enums;
```

In this the DotNet has a blue squiggly under it.
and the reference "DotNet.Highcharts" in the my references folder.

I am using VS 2012 Professional (if that matters)

Do I need to add something in my webconfig that I am missing or do I need to set a reference path? I have used nuget packages before and not ran across this problem so not sure what I need to do.

What I have done.

- Restarted VS
- Closed / Reopen project
- Start from scratch project (mvc 4 empty) and added in DotNet.Highcharts and Jquery packages from nuget and followed the tutorial I listed above.

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace HighChart.Models
{
    public class TransactionCount
    {
        public string MonthName { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using HighChart.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DotNet.Highcharts;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Enums;

namespace HighChart.Controllers
{
    public class ChartSampleController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ChartSample/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var transactionCounts = new List<TransactionCount> {
            new TransactionCount() { MonthName="January", Count=30},
            new TransactionCount() { MonthName="February", Count=40},
            new TransactionCount() { MonthName="March", Count=4},
            new TransactionCount() { MonthName="April", Count=35}
            };

            var xDataMonths = transactionCounts.Select(i => i.MonthName).ToArray();
            var yDataCounts = transactionCounts.Select(i => new object[] { i.Count }).ToArray();


            //instanciate an object o the highcharts type
            var chart = new Highcharts("chart")
                //define the type of chart
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line })
                //overall title of the chart
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Incoming Transactions per hour" })
                //small lable below the main title
            .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "Accounting" })
                //load the X values
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = xDataMonths })
                //set the Y Title
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Number of Transactions" } })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Formatter = @"function () { return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>'+ this.x +': '+ this.y; }"
            })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Line = new PlotOptionsLine
                {
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsLineDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true
                    },
                    EnableMouseTracking = false
                }
            })
                //load the Y values
            .SetSeries(new[]
            {
                new Series {Name = "Hour", Data = new Data(yDataCounts)},
                //you can add more y data to create a second line
                // new series { Name = "Other Name", Data = new Data(OtherData)}
            });
            return View(chart);
            //return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts
        <p>My Chart</p>
        @(Model)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update target framework above 4.0.. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the dll to the references? You will need to do this manually by browsing to the dll location.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to specifically download the "Net 4.0" DLL.
https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/121251

I honestly thought the nuget package would take care of this